# Chatbot creation on GCP with data on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, chatbot

I have a requirement to build an Interactive chatbot to answer Queries from Users .

We get different source files from different source systems and we are maintaining log of when files arrived, when they processed etc in a csv file on google cloud storage. Every 30 mins csv gets generated with log of any new file which arrived and being stored on GCP.

Users keep on asking via mails whether Files arrived or not, which file yet to come etc.

If we can make a chatbot which can read csv data on GCS and can answer User queries then it will be a great help in terms of response times.

Can this be achieved via chatbot?

If so, please help with most suitable tools/Coding language to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in several ways. All depends what are your requirements in response time and CSV size

- [Use BigQuery and external table (also called federated table)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). When you define it, you can choose a file (or a file pattern) in GCS, like a csv. Then you can query your data with a simple SQL query. This solution is cheap and easy to deploy. But Bigquery has latency (depends of your file size, but can take several seconds)
- Use [Cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) and [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/). When the new CSV file is generated, [plug a function on this event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage). The function parse the file and insert data into Cloud SQL. Be careful, the function can live up to 9 minutes and max 2Gb can be assign to it. If your file is too large, you can break these limit (time and/or memory). The main advantage is the latency (set the correct index and your query is answered in millis)
- Use nothing! In the fulfillment endpoint, get your CSV file, parse it and find what you want. Then release it. Here, you do nothing, but the latency is terrible, the processing huge, you have to repeat the file download and parse,... Ugly solution, but can work if your file is not too large for being in memory

We can also imagine more complex solution with dataflow, but I feel that isn't your target.

Comment: Hi ..Thanks for answering.Apologies If i have not been clear on requirements.  I know, I can load the logs file in BQ or in SQL. I want to create chatbot with log files which can read the file and answer the user queries on status of source files arrivals timing. Looking for a good solution to create chatbot on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: It was clear for me: your CSV is the list of files with their arrival date, and it's updated every 30 minutes. But I don't understand your pain points. You can create your chatbot with [dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/), define a fulfillment endpoint and process the query in this endpoint for answering the correct value to your Chatbot. This value can be found in BigQuery or CloudSQL.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know if there is any alternative as dialogflow is not yet approved service to use in organization.

Comment: There is other Chatbot platform (some provided by [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/services/bot-service/) or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/chatbot/)), other independant. However, Dialogflow is one of the most efficient and I can't recommend something else. So, keep in mind that Dialogflow is a platform for designing/testing your Chatbot. Then you extract your model and you can host it where you want. This isn't the case with the other solution of Azure and AWS